# How to remove part of line after ":" in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to delete first part of email:pass. Keeping everything after ":"

EXAMPLE:
test0@aol.com:a59e1bbbdb3bd9d8e6be1651ac59ca5f
to
a59e1bbbdb3bd9d8e6be1651ac59ca5f

Comment: Do your lines only have a single :?

Comment: Use something like `s/^.*://g`.

Comment: @Zoredache Notepad++ doesn't support the /// syntax . . . you have to do find and replace dialogs, so it'd be more like `^.*:(.*)$` in the find box, and in the replace, you'd have `\1`.  Though I'll point out that the title to this question suggests wanting the exact opposite of what the question asks (remove the part after the :, as opposed to keeping it)

Comment: You’ll definitely want to use a regular expression, but the specific expression that you will need to use will depend on your specific data. For example, if *all* of your lines are exactly like your sample, then something as simple as `^.+:(.+)$` → `\1` would work. If that was a simplified example, then you would need to account for the variations, which could get complex (the [full regex for email addresses](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) alone is mind-boggling).

Answer (score 3):

Applying **Zoredache** answer in comment:

In "Search and Replace" dialogue box (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Under "Search Mode", Choose "**Regular Expression**"

Under "Find What: ", paste

`^.*:`

Click "Replace All"

---

**Explanation of PCRE**

^ Beginning of the string

. Any character

* Zero or more previous character (greedy)

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace with a regular expression (check box down on the left).  The find field could be something like:

`^[^:]+:`

Translated it means From the beginning of the line (^) take everything that isn't a colon ([^:]+) and the colon delimiter (:).

The replace field would be empty.